# ResearchGate Requests

Tags: publications

I have received full texts requests for my articles, but at that moment I did not carry them so I answered "I don't have a full text I can share", and sent a message to the requesters. Nowadays, I have got the full texts and I want to send them, but those previous requests do not appear anymore.
How can I recover those requests?

Comment: ResearchGate is just the worst.  You are talking to an AI that tries to 'trick' you into enriching the site.     I believe you can search for your article's name, and then upon clicking on it, there will be a button for you to upload your article.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus "*x* is just the worst. You are talking to an AI that tries to 'trick' you into enriching the site."
valid ∀ *x* ∈ [Meta, Alpha, Microsoft, Apple, Canonical, ...]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, ResearchGate is helpful site

Comment: @EarlGrey Do the entities in the set pretend to be you and send out unsolicited emails to you?

Comment: @Mathematics Useful to get spammed.  Indeed!

Comment: I think you can track who sent you request. Go to the ResearchGate page, there are 3 box (Update box, Message box and Request box) on the upper right corner of monitor. Click on message box, I hope you can see who sent request in the past

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mathematics. I have searched all the requests and found some since 2016, but specifically, those that I answered with "I didn't have the full texts" do not appear.